# How to create a fourth level wildcard subdomain DNS record ?

Tags: wildcards, subdomain

I would like to create subdomain tag.example.com and then fourth level wildcard subdomain DNS record over that one.
I mean *.tag.example.com
Is this possible ? and if so how ?

Comment: What are you using to serve out DNS records? If it's bind, it should be straightforward enough.

Comment: I use dnsmadeeasy.com

Comment: A quick google throws up https://support.dnsmadeeasy.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=26. Never used them, so I can't help further unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards are possible at *any* level. The only limit, which applies to both wildcards and normal subdomains, is that there can be at most 63 dot-separated components.